# concatenating matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a list of matrices. How would I append these matrices to get a single matrix?

Sample:

```
> matrix(1, nrow=2, ncol=3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    1
> matrix(2, nrow=3, ncol=2)
     [,1] [,2] 
[1,]    2    2 
[2,]    2    2 
[3,]    2    2 
> m1 <- matrix(1, nrow=2, ncol=3)
> m2 <- matrix(2, nrow=3, ncol=2)
```

Now we can have many matrices in a list, let's say we have only two:

```
l <- list(m1, m2)
```

I would like to achieve something like:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]                  2    2    
[4,]                  2    2    
[5,]                  2    2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `bdiag`

```
library(Matrix)
bdiag(l)
#5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#          
#[1,] 1 1 1 . .
#[2,] 1 1 1 . .
#[3,] . . . 2 2
#[4,] . . . 2 2
#[5,] . . . 2 2

 as.matrix(bdiag(l)) #will convert to `matrix` with `0` replacing the `.`
```